# Determine all points where 2 variable function is differentiable: when to use definition?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My function is:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x\sin^2 y}{x^2+y^2}\text{ when }(x,y) \ne (0,0)$$

and $0$ when $(x,y) = (0,0)$

When I use the definition (limit as $h$ approaches $0$), the limit for both partiales equals $0$. 
Or i know I could just differentiate using the chain and quotient rules.

I don't understand which method I should use when.

Since using the definition, I get 0 for both partials, then $L(x,y) = 0$
So I have to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}  |R(x,y)| / |(x,y)-(0,0)$ goes to zero. That would prove that it is differentiable everywhere.

Is there anything that I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Where you wrote $x\sin^2 y / x^2+y^2$, might you have meant $x\sin^2 y / (x^2+y^2)$?  If so you could also write $\displaystyle\frac{x\sin^2 y}{x^2+y^2}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. I'm not very good with formatting yet...

Comment: @Bob, fixed. While you can not infer differentiability from the existence of partials, you can note that if differentiable that $DF$ is unique. The goal here is to try and get a bound on $f(x,y)$.

Comment: I tried to do that, and ended up with 1/($x^{2}+y^{2}$). And as (x,y)->(0,0), it still does not exist. Does that mean its not differentiable at (0,0)?